# Is there a word that means "thoughtful-looking"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't mean "thoughtful" as in considerate or generous, but one who considers the actions of others and tries to make sense of them.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean pensive?

Comment: Also contemplative.

Comment: As per the tag info 'To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pensive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pensive) might suit your needs:

> Engaged in, involving, or reflecting deep or serious thought.

(Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELU! I like your suggestion, and it's great that you included a definition. I've edited in a source and citation that matches the definition you cited, which are both generally required here; feel free to edit further if you found the definition somewhere else. Your answer could also be strengthened by a sentence or two explaining why *you* think this word fits, so there's a bit more of your own expertise in it. I look forward to your future contributions!